# Unable to see the "Admin" tab in BI Publisher on OBIEE 10.1.3.4

Tags: obiee

I have successfully deployed OBIEE 10g (10.1.3.4) on my workstation with BI Publisher being part of the installation.

However, when I login to BI Publisher using "Administrator" I'm unable to see the "Admin" tab. Nor I'm able to view the share folders or create a new report.
On clicking the shared folders, following error is shown. I'm sure this is something to do with access rights / security groups configuration.

Error
Unauthorized Access: please contact the administrator.

Kindly help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have login with the administrator priviledge.
When you installed it gives you a username and password. Make sure you used that.